# Send reply in RabbitListenerErrorHandler but still NACK message?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a pipeline of services processing a task using Spring Boot and RabbitMQ.

Each service consumes messages from a queue, does some work, and re-sends that work as a message to be processed by the next service.

During each step in the process, I am sending **another** message to a central queue with a status update for that task (to be persisted in a DB).

I have implemented error handling according to [this article](https://programmerfriend.com/rabbit-mq-retry/). In short: on error the message is rejected to a DLQ with a TTL and requeued to the main queue.

In the error handler I distinguish between fatal (business) exceptions and retryable exceptions.

I implemented it as such:

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = "task.step.first", errorHandler = "customErrorHandler")
    @SendTo("task.status")
    public Status process(Task task) {

        // Check if retries < max

        // Do some heavy work. Create nextTask

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("task.step.second", nextTask);

        return new Status("Step 1 Success!");
    }
```

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorHandler implements RabbitListenerErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public Object handleError(Message amqpMessage,
            org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message,
            ListenerExecutionFailedException exception) throws Exception {

        // Check if error is fatal or retryable
        if (exception.getCause() /* ..is fatal? */) {
            return new Status("FAIL!");
        }

        // Unknown exception, rethrow it and let message to be NACKed and retried via DLQ 
        // How to still send 'new Status("Retrying...")' here while NACKing the message?
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

As you can see I don't really know how to handle the bottom scenario.

I want to **(re)throw** the original exception in the error handler, causing the message to be NACK'ed, routed to the DLQ and retried, but I **also** want to send back an intermediate Status message as a reply.

Of course I can inject the `RabbitTemplate` in the `CustomErrorHandler` directly and send a status message manually to the `@SendTo` queue, but I wonder if there is a better way to leverage the reply channel directly without having to manually inject another RabbitTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting use case.

If you use `MANUAL` ack mode, you could do this in your listener...

```java
public Status process(Task task, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long deliveryTAG) {

...

    if (good) {
        channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
        return status;
    }
    else {
        throw someException
    }
```

And then, in the error handler, `channel.basicReject()`, instead of throwing the exception.

The channel is available in the `Message` `AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL` header along with the DELIVERY_TAG.

The channel was added to the headers in 2.2.0 and 2.1.7. It is not available in earlier versions.